# Android PageViewer - Hiding Status Bar for Specific Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, statusbar

This is my first time posting here, so I'll try to be as specific as possible.

### Background

I'm currently building an android app and I've come across a problem with hiding the Status Bar. Let me set this up. I'm using a `ViewPager` to allow the user to swipe between two full-screen pages. In each page is a unique `Fragment`. One has a live camera, the other has a list. What I would like to do is hide the Status Bar at the top of the camera fragment, and slide it down when going to the list. This essential what SnapChat does while going from the camera fragment to a non-camera fragment. How they implement it is the ultimate goal.

My minSdkVersion is 17, so I can use this snippet that Google offers on [this Android training site](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#41):

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

### Problem

This works very well at hiding and (with a few changes) showing the status bar. However, this introduces another problem where a blank white space now appears where the status bar once was. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJC8U.jpg).

I cannot figure out how to make this disappear. I *think* that the layout needs to be adjusted to stretch all the way to the top, but I can't quite figure it out.

So,

1. White space appears when hiding Status Bar
2. Make white space black, instead.

### Code

From my PageChangeListener:

```
public void onPageSelected(int position)
{
    if (fragments[position] instanceof CameraPreviewFragment)
    {
        hideStatusBar();
    }
    else
    {
        showStatusBar();
    }
}
```

The two methods:

```
public void hideStatusBar()
{
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}

public void showStatusBar()
{
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

If you need anymore code or the views, I'll edit the post to include them. Appreciate it!

Comment: Try moving that to `onPageScrollStateChanged()` and see if that solves the white space problem

Comment: @LittleChild If I move the show/hide to that spot, I lose what position I'm at. Also, this problem occurs from the very beginning; the blank space appears there from the start.